# How to prevent net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING when using HTML5 Server events and Java Servlets?

Tags: java, google-chrome, servlet-3.0, server-sent-events

i just started to play around with Server Events and i run into a chrome error message i would like to understand. i searched the web real quick but didn't find an explanation so i guess i may do something terribly wrong.

On the server side i have a simple servlet that accepts requests and creates a dummy event creator task:

```
private Executor executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void doGet(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response)
{
  final AsyncContext asynCtx = request.startAsync(request, response);

  response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
  response.setContentType("text/event-stream");
  response.setCharacterEncoding("utf-8");

  executor.execute(() -> {
    boolean run = true;
    try
    {
      while (run)
      {
        final ServletResponse resp = asynCtx.getResponse();
        run = resp != null;

        if (resp != null)
        {
          System.out.println("pushing a server event.");
          final PrintWriter writer = asynCtx.getResponse().getWriter();
          writer.println("data: {time: " + System.currentTimeMillis() + "}\n");
          writer.flush();
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("stopping beeper, no response object available anymore.");
          break; // do not run anymore, we got no response
        }

        Thread.sleep(2000);
      }
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  });

}
```

on the client i simply:

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{

   var source = new EventSource("/events");
   source.onmessage = function (event)
   {
     console.log("received event: " + JSON.stringify(event));
     document.getElementById("eventContainer").innerHTML += event.data + "<br/>";
   };

   console.log("start to receive events...")
});
```

when i load the HTML file it works fine, events are received and written to the console. But **after 30 seconds** i get an error message:

**GET [HttpOfLocalhost]/events net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING**

why?

the request than gets killed and a new one is started immediately so it doesn't kill the application but error messages on the console aren't nice.

screenshot of my developer console:

[image]

request/resposne details:

[image]

timing, this shows that it always occurs after 30 seconds:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so i couldn't stand still and look closer whats happening.

The [AsyncContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) object has a [setTimeout(...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#getTimeout()) method. Per default in my version of tomcat (Tomcat embedded 8) the value is set to 30,000 ms (30 seconds). That's exactly the duration after i got the *net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING* error in my chrome console.

i checked using:

```
System.out.println("Current Timeout is: " + asynCtx.getTimeout() + " ms");
```

which showed:

```
Current Timeout is: 30000 ms
```

so to avoid the net:ERR message someone could set the timeout to 0. But than the event thread keeps running forever (unfortunately). 
Another solution, which i used, is to add a [AsyncListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncListener.html) to the [AsyncContext](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html) and call the [complete()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncContext.html#complete()) method inside the [onTimeout()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/AsyncListener.html#onTimeout(javax.servlet.AsyncEvent)) method.

from the API doc of the complete() method:

> Completes the asynchronous operation that was started on the request
>   that was used to initialze this AsyncContext, closing the response
>   that was used to initialize this AsyncContext. Any listeners of type
>   AsyncListener that were registered with the ServletRequest for which
>   this AsyncContext was created will be invoked at their onComplete
>   method.

the source code of my listener:

```
asynCtx.addListener(new AsyncListener()
{
  @Override
  public void onComplete(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("onComplete(...)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onTimeout(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException
  {
    // this will close the request and the context gracefully
    // and the net:ERR is gone.
    asyncEvent.getAsyncContext().complete();
    System.out.println("onTimeout(...)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("onError(...)");
  }

  @Override
  public void onStartAsync(AsyncEvent asyncEvent) throws IOException
  {
    System.out.println("onStart(...)");
  }
});
```

so yes, it was due lack of knowledge. i hope this is helpful for someone.

Comment: Tell me please. I have this error, but I do not use Asynk. I go to the page and I have this error.

Answer (score 3):

You can send small "no operation" (noop) chunks to keep the connection alive every 10 seconds or so.