# Tomcat 7 INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: spring, google-chrome, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-security

Well, hello SO community, 
I having a specific issue with my Tomcat 7 server, 
I went deep on the web about this error, but I only found answers about

> net::INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

I am using Spring MVC, including Integration, Security and JDBC modules (I do not think Spring has something to do with this), and no special config on my server.

I just found answers about tomcat 8 using AsyncContext, but I am not using any async features, found that some antivirus (ESET on most cases) is causing problems with chunked encoding, but my server just has a firewall with the respective rules for http
Also there are some forums that says I must change my browser settings (specially Chrome), but this is happening even on FF and IE

The error is showing on the page load (I saw this error is mostly caused by some css or js resources that were not found)

This is my request info

> GET /admin/home HTTP/1.1
>   Host: myhost.com
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Cache-Control: max-age=0
>   Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
>   User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
>   Cookie: JSESSIONID=72365yMY_COOKIE_jifhdwit2435346534

And my response

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
>   Pragma: no-cache
>   Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
>   Cache-Control: no-cache
>   Cache-Control: no-store
>   Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
>   Content-Language: en-US
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked

So, does it has something to do with Spring framework? Do I have to add an extra config to my Tomcat server?

Comment: Q: Are you making an Async server call?  If so, look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26863972/how-to-prevent-neterr-incomplete-chunked-encoding-when-using-html5-server-even) link.  Q: What exactly is your code doing when the error occurs?  Do you have a stack trackback?>

Comment: 1) No, I'm not making an async call
2) Well, my controller just return a view with its model, I'm not doing any special request or something

Comment: Q: Stack trace?  Error logs?  Relevant code snippet?  Please update your post: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi .. Were you able to fix it .. I am facing the same error .. thanks.